# Swift project - override properties of my own framework class/struct

Tags: swift

In my workspace I have multiple app projects. They only need to declare their constants. There is no other code in the app projects. App projects only contain one AppSettings file and few data files (all app projects contain the data files in the same format but with different content). Rest all code is in a framework project of my own. How can I override only some constants from the framework?

```
    //in framework project: 
            struct AppSettings {

                static let columnCountLandscape: Int = 0
                static let columnCountPortrait: Int = 0
                static let appName: String = "base"
                static let imageZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
                static let version: String = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String ?? ""
                static let applicationType: String = ""

    }

    @main
    struct MyFramework: App {
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                    switch AppSettings.applicationType {
                    case "A": AView()
                    case "B": BView()
                    case "C": CView()
                    default: EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Child project
    
    struct AppSettings {

          static let appName: "MyApp"
          static let columnCountLandscape: Int = 3
          static let applicationType: String = "B"

    }
```

Comment: Why not make all of them `var`s so that you can set them whenever you want?

Comment: tried that too but still framework's values are taken instead of child project's values when child project's target is run.

Comment: When do you read the values? Did you read them before they are set by the child project? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Will try to create an example, meanwhile have updated my question and included the very first place where AppSettings are read

Comment: So `AppSettings` are first read in the framework project? That will be quite difficult.

Comment: Yes all source code exists only in the framework. Child App projects only have data and one settings file. Will changing framework project to normal Xcode project help in any way.?